# How do I iterate all rows from two tables connected by foreign key into a single table in PHP, CodeIgniter, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Say I have Table A and Table B in my SQL database.

TABLE A (Users)

| userID | Name | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userA | John | 2292 |
| userB | Dave | 3383 |

TABLE B (Sports)

| sportID | Name | trainer_userID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sportA | Basketball | userB |
| sportB | Baseball | userA |
| sportC | Soccer | userC |

On my PHP page, I want to combine the two tables, such that the foreign key trainer_userID connects to their respective users. I can already iterate through each users and show Table A, but can't think of ways to combine both  tables such that the output would be:

| userID | Name | Contact | Sport Handled ID | Sport Handled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| userA | John | 2292 | sportB | Baseball |
| userB | Dave | 3383 | sportA | BasketBall |

Comment: Look up JOINS in SQL. This is exactly what relational databases are for. Don't implement sql in loop, databases do it better. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Got it. That was a very helpful tip, would remember it on my journey. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> Look up JOINS in SQL. This is exactly what relational databases are
> for. Don't implement sql in loop, databases do it better. Welcome to
> SO. – danblack 35 mins ago

Solved my problem using the JOINS technique and by using databases instead of looping.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
   ON tableA.userID = tableB.trainer_userID;
```